# Windows phone 8.1 is terminated when phone locks

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I am facing this weird issue with a windows 8.1 app I created.
All the other apps I have already made stay in the app stack when the phone is locked, until I close them

This app however is closed after a minute when the phone is locked, and it is not in the app stack, I have to restart it.

It is an app that consumes a webservice, so it does not consume loads of resources when the phone is locked.
When I debug it with Visual studio the app stays alive all the time.
The problem occurs on the phone, not in debug mode.

I have almost no code in the app.cs, only thing I have changed is thr start startpage.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: There may be a problem with *Suspension*, while you are debugging the app is not being suspended, thus there may be no exception. Debug your app with lifecycle events. Maybe you are passing some complex class with *Navigate* method.

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer ! I was using a complex type and passed that as parameter. Serialization it, was the answer to my problem!